# QM result which implies equality in uncertainty relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In Sakurai, there is a result in chapter 1 which states "the equality sign in the generalized uncertainty relation holds if the state in question satisfies

$$\Delta A| \alpha \rangle = \lambda  \Delta B | \alpha \rangle$$
with $\lambda$ purely imaginary." But then in a different problem in chapter 2, he states that the above result is applicable for the free-particle wave packet in one dimension since at time $t = 0$ it satisfies the minimum uncertainty relation $$\langle ( \Delta x )^2 \rangle \langle ( \Delta p)^2 \rangle = \frac{\hbar^2}{4} \implies \text{there exists }~\lambda \text{ such that }\Delta x(0)|t=0\rangle = \lambda \Delta p(0)|t=0 \rangle .$$

From the way I see it the first result implies the equality of the uncertainty relation not the other way around, does anyone know if the first result is actually an if and only if statement? Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess the simplest way in which the statement in the Chap.2 problem may make sense is if "free-particle wave packet" actually refers to "free-particle *Gaussian* wave packet". Otherwise the relation for $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$ is reminiscent of a simultaneous diagonalization of non-commuting observables A and B ($A|\mu\rangle = \lambda_\mu B|\mu\rangle$), but 1) such a diagonalization can only work if B is strictly positive definite; 2) because it involves $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$, the relation is actually nonlinear in $|\alpha\rangle$, unlike a simultaneous diagonalization.

Comment: @urdv So the above result applies for a free-particle Gaussian wave packet?

Comment: That's my best guess. But right now it's also another way of saying "I'm not aware of any proof of equivalence or lack thereof".